# Programmatically create a site collection in an existing, mounted content database

Tags: 2010, development, content-database

I'd like to create a site collection from a custom application page in central admin. The administrator needs the option to specify an existing, mounted content database to store the new site collection. I'm running SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Creating a site collection with PowerShell allows an existing mounted content database to be specified, but none of the `SPSiteCollection.Add()` object model overloads allow the same. I can create a new database, but not specify an existing database.

Browsing the Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell assembly with Reflector shows the `New-SPSite` cmdlet uses an additional, internally scoped `SPSiteCollection.Add()` overload that includes a content database parameter. I assume the Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell assembly is listed in an InternalsVisibleToAttribute in the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly, allowing PowerShell access to the internal function while remaining hidden to my code.

I'm aware that I can [execute PowerShell scripts from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HowToRunPowerShell.aspx), is there any reason not to do this by calling the `New-SPSite` cmdlet from code? Is there any other method I've missed?

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell is just a wrapper for the object model. You shouldn't need to reference PowerShell in your feature, just create the new site collection with C# inside your feature. There's a blog post here that illustrates some code that may get you started. http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-sites-site-collections-custom-web-template/

Comment: Creating a site collection while specifying a pre-mounted content database appears to be something you can **only** do with PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding the new SPSite using the SPContentDatabase object instead of the SPWebApplication object.

```
 SPContentDatabase myDB = ......
 myDb.Sites.Add("/Sites/Name", "domain\login","email@x.com");
```

There are also many 6 other overloads of that function